# Ошибки при парсинге aiohttp

Tags: python

> {'errors': [{'message': 'PersistedQueryNotFound', 'extensions':
> {'code': 'PERSISTED_QUERY_NOT_FOUND'}}]}

Вот ошибка, посмотрел, похоже это не ответ сервера, а именно ошибка при отправке запроса, не всегда, но из 100 запросов 10 будет с ошибкой, как бороться?

Comment: Похоже страница, которую вы парсите меняется и парсер не может найти запрошенную часть. Приведите пример того, что вы хотите спарсить и как запрос отправляете.

Comment: Похоже проблема была на сервере, сейчас тесты делаю и ошибок нет